# Python script to monitor disk space from df and send e-mail alert when over threshold

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, ubuntu

I've been attempting to write a script for the past 2 days that will monitor the disks that appear when using the command df in Ubuntu. I've been having trouble finding a method that will give me the name of the disk and the percentage that is being used. I'm just beginning on python and Ubuntu so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't gotten to the e-mail part yet, I've tried many different ways to output the disk name and percentage from the df command but nothing that I've read online has helped me yet

Comment: Divide and conquer. Divide your task in subtasks and test from command line

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Thank you for that link, this is my first post so I wasn't aware of that thread. I will make sure to explain better next time I post.

Answer (score 4):

I know a way to check disk space occupied percent in Python. Just write a python script and add this lines:

```
import os

s = os.statvfs(PATH_TO_DEVICE)
diskSpacePercent =  round((((s.f_blocks - s.f_bfree) * s.f_frsize)/(s.f_blocks * s.f_bsize)) * 100, 2)

print diskSpacePercent
```

After, run the script via shellscript or shell and you will have disk space percent of device

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. Do you know if it's possible to iterate through every disk that shows when using the df command in ubuntu?

Comment: I think if you want to show all disks/devices, you need to set manually each one. Maybe you can create a shell script to get the device paths (via cat or pipe '|') and pass then like parameters in your python function

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to send you the name and usage :

```
df -hl |cut -d$'\t' -f2
```

See using `mailx` or `uuencode` to send emails via Unix.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pipe to cut or any other parsing commands just use the output flag:

```
df -h --output=source,pcent
```